# Expression inside expression in handebars

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Is there any way to put `{{expression params={{expression}}}}` I have code like this `{{name value={{place}}}}` where `name` and place are `expressions`.The problem is I cannot do this in js and i wanted this to be done in handlebars So is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation. https://handlebarsjs.com/ You will find some examples there too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do `{{expression params=(subexpression)}}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest subexpressions in handlebars with parenthesis. A common example is using the hash helper to pass a nested object to a component

```
{{name value=(hash prop1="a" prop2=(hash sub1="x" sub2="y"))}}

passes the following object to value

{
  prop1: "a",
  prop2: {
    sub1: "x",
    sub2: "y"
  }
}
```